# how to change gnuplot's graph size

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a graph with increased font size in gnuplot. A typical example is:

```
p sin(x) w l lw 5
set border lw 4
set tics font "Halvetica Bold,20"
```

So, I am trying to have:

1. adjust plot size without changing the canvas size to accommodate x/y label and tics
2. to adjust space between tics and label

How can I achieve this?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The margins and the label positions depend on the total font size. You can specify this as part of the `set terminal` command.

The following script gives good margins and label positions:

```
set terminal wxt font ",20"
set border lw 4
plot sin(x) lw 5
```

For your example, you could adjust the margins with `set lmargin ...` and similar commands, and adjust the tic offset with `set xtics offset ...`:

```
set terminal wxt
set border lw 4
set tics font "Halvetica Bold,20"
set bmargin 3
set lmargin 10
set xtic offset 0,-1
set ytics offset -0.5,0
plot sin(x) lw 5
```